# Is "offer sb with sth" ungrammatical? If it is, why do so many people use them?

Tags: grammar

I've looked in all the major dictionaries and there is no such way of using "offer."

1. I offered him with a raise. <= incorrect (according to dictionaries)
2. I offered him a raise. <= correct

But a quick Google search shows that many people use (1). Is it because it's correct or is it because it's natural to some people?

Comment: The search was too quick. Google tells me _No results found for "I offered him with a raise"._

Comment: @john https://www.google.com/search?q=%22offered+him+with+a%22

Comment: @user814064, most of the hits in that Google search are not the same thing as ‘offering someone with a job’. Rather than being of the type, “She offered him a job”, they are of the type, “She offered him a job, with a smile”; i.e., the ‘with’ clause is not directly connected to the verb ‘offer’.

Comment: Thanks.
I didn't search for "I offered him with a raise" exactly.
Try "offered her with", "offered them with" or "offered him with" instead.

Comment: You may have seen a construction where _with_ went with the object, not the verb. For example, _I offered him spaghetti with meatballs._

Comment: That can't be the case. The quotation marks make sure _with_ stands right next to the _pronoun_.

Answer (score 5):

**I offered him with a raise* is not correct. I don't know where you read that construction, but I don't recall ever seeing it.

Perhaps this happens sometimes when people confuse it with constructions like *I presented him with something* and *I gifted him with something*.

From the *Oxford English Dictionary* on the verb *present*:

> 11.a. trans. "To bring or place (a thing) before or into the presence of a person, or to put (it) into his hands, for acceptance; to offer, proffer, deliver, hand over, bestow, give (usually in a formal or ceremonious manner)."
>
> ...
>
> 13.a. *to present a person with a thing* = "to present a thing to a person" (sense 11). Formerly in the full extent of sense 11; now always implying bestowal of something as a gift to be kept (11 (a)). Also fig. "to furnish or supply with something". ...
>
> ... 1831 Southey Lett. (1856) IV. 247 *Mrs. Bray...has desired to present you with a copy of Mary Colling's poem.*

The verb *offer* has no such construction.

Comment: Even _I presented him (with) something_ would usually use a direct object rather than a preposition.

Comment: @BraddSzonye: But at least it is possible...

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's generally acceptable. I checked a few dictionaries, and the intransitive senses of _present_ relate to manifestation (esp. of medical conditions) rather than giving. Also, _presented him with_ has the same problem of an indirect object without a direct object. I think I've heard it before, but think it's colloquial and pleonastic.

Comment: I dug a little deeper and discovered that _present_ has a transitive sense meaning “give to.” Thus, _him_ is actually the **direct** object in _presented him with,_ and the prepositional phrase describes how he's presented.

Comment: @BraddSzonye: Umm perhaps we are talking about a different sense of *present*. I am talking about *I presented him with a book* = *I offered him a book*. OED: 13a. *to present a person with a thing* = "to present a thing to a person" (sense 11). Formerly in the full extent of sense 11; now always implying bestowal of something as a gift to be kept (11 (a)). Also fig. "to furnish or supply with something". ... 1831 Southey Lett. (1856) IV. 247 *Mrs. Bray...has desired to present you with a copy of Mary Colling's poem.*

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize that _present_ has two similar senses such that the direct object can be the gift **or** the recipient.

Answer (score 1):

[*Offer*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/offer) in this sense is normally transitive, with the thing offered (*a raise*) as direct object and the recipient (*him*) as indirect object:

> I offered (him) a raise.

Most dictionaries also attest a few intransitive senses of *offer,* but in practice they are used in specialized or archaic contexts. For example:

> “That's not a raise, that's an insult,” he objected.
>   “Hey, I **offerred.**”

Furthermore, English does not usually permit an [indirect object without a direct object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28grammar%29#Types_of_objects), so it's unnatural to write “I offered **him**” with a prepositional phrase instead of a direct object. In contrast, it's fine to omit the indirect object or replace it with a prepositional phrase:

> I offered a raise (to him).

Comment: My gripe is not with the absence of an object, which is possible in examples like your, but with using *with* to introduce the thing given. Would you really consider that possible at all? I mean, sure, I can make unlikely but possible sentences like *I offered him with a raise a chance to escape poverty*. But that is surely not what the OP intended...

Comment: Actually, after digging into the grammar of _presented_ and _gifted,_ I realized that my answer here is slightly off the mark. The problem is not the lack of the object, but that the wrong thing is the object (_him_ instead of _a raise_).

Comment: Exactly! That switch is possible with some verbs, but not with *offer*.